# Refactoring copy function C++

Tags: c++

Error C2676 binary '==': 'const stackADT' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

I am getting the above error for the line of code below. I can how handle the error.

N/B: lit is a vector

I was to modify the stack implementation such that it uses a vectors as the container instead of an array.

I was also to overload the pure virtual function push such that it takes a vector as an argument which pushes multiple values onto the stack.

```
template<class Type>
bool stackType<Type>::operator==(const stackType& rhs) const {
return static_cast<const stackADT<Type>&>(*this) == static_cast<const stackADT<Type>&>(rhs) &&
    lit == rhs.lit;
}
```

**Heres the class being referenced**

```
#ifndef VECTORIMPLEMENTATION_STACKADT_H
#define VECTORIMPLEMENTATION_STACKADT_H

template <class Type>
class stackADT
{
public:
//Initializes to empty stack state method.
virtual void initializeStack() = 0;

//checks whether stack is empty.
virtual bool isEmptyStack() const = 0;

//checks whether stack is full.
virtual bool isFullStack() const = 0;

//Adds new item to the stack.
virtual void push(const Type& newItem) = 0;

//Returns the top most element in the stack.
virtual Type top() const = 0;

//Remove the top most element in the stack.
virtual void pop() = 0;

};
#endif //VECTORIMPLEMENTATION_STACKADT_H
```

Comment: Neither vector nor (apparently) your `stackADT` type define `op==`, so why did you expect it to work?

Comment: Also a typo: operator==(const stackType`<Type>`& rhs) const

Comment: It is code for the (templated) `stackADT` that is relevant to the question.  `stackType`s `operator==()` tries to make use of `stackADT`s `operator==()` - the error message indicates `stackADT` has no such operator.

Comment: @peter I added the stackADT. Check it out

Comment: An abstract class (sometimes called an "interface" because Java) is not the same as an abstract datatype.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't get what you are trying to say please

Comment: @denim `const stackADT does not define this operator` -- Well, I'm looking hard, but I don't see an `operator=` for `stackADT`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  how can I do that?

Comment: `stackADT` does not have an `operator==()`.   The comparison `static_cast<const stackADT<Type>&>(*this) == static_cast<const stackADT<Type>&>(rhs) ` will try to call such an `operator==()`, so the compiler rejects it.     Since `stackADT` is an abstract class (no data members, cannot be instantiated since it has pure virtual member functions) it's not clear what you expect to gain by comparing them for equality.